# EC2 Boto connection gives None

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I get None when I run this code

```
import boto.ec2

with open('rootkey.csv') as f:
    csv = f.readlines()

conn =  boto.ec2.connect_to_region(
    "eu-west-2a",
    aws_access_key_id = csv[0].split('=')[1],
    aws_secret_access_key = csv[1].split('=')[1])

print(conn)
```

(trying to connect to a AmazonLinux instance on AWS EC2 from MAC with python)

Comment: can you check the type of `conn?. Most probably the function is returning `None` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**eu-west-2a** is an availability zone, not a region. Change it to **eu-west-2**

```
>>> conn =  boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-2a')
>>> print conn
None
>>> conn =  boto.ec2.connect_to_region('eu-west-2')
>>> print conn
EC2Connection:ec2.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```